# Python lambda function declaration and call for list generation

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, lambda

In generating a list as below, the lambda function is declared outside the squared brackets, then applied for each `i`,

```
>>> g = lambda x: x*10
>>> [g(i) for i in range(10,21)]
[100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190, 200]
```

Is it possible (and how) to declare the lambda function within the list and call it ?

Comment: First guess: `[(lambda x: x*10)(i) for i in range(10,21)]`. Why do you feel you want to do this?

Comment: You'll end up producing slow and unreadable code

Comment: @enzyme Be careful, short code does not always mean efficient code in Python.

Comment: you would never ever want to do this. a lambda is just a one-line function and you can easily just put its body inside the list comprehension.

Comment: Assigning a lambda to a variable is rarely correct but a bunch of horrible lambda tutorials do it anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The insane way:

```
[(lambda x: x*10)(i) for i in range(10,21)]
```

The sane way:

```
[i * 10 for i in range(10,21)]
```

Comment: Explanation: The problem with declaring the lambda function in the comprehension is that the function will be repeatedly created for each item in the list.  Since the body of a lambda is a single expression, it is better to put that expression directly into the comprehension.

Answer (score 3):

you can use map too:

```
>>> list(map(lambda x:x*10,range(10,21)))
[100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190, 200]
```

Comment: Great answer except that `map` returns a list so doesn't need to be converted.

Comment: oops, should have thought about that. the comment is true for python 2.

Comment: Grt by urself you realize it :)

Comment: @tdelaney Python 2 version: `map(lambda x:x*10, xrange(10,21))`.